# Possible bug in Spring JPA & Lazy Loading of self-referential property

Tags: jpa, lazy-loading

Let's say I have a class named BusinessCategory:

```java
    @Entity
    public class BusinessCategory implements Serializable{

    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    private BusinessCategory parentCategory;
    ...
    }
```

where parentCategory is to be lazily loaded.  Another class named `Transaction` that has within it a `BusinessCategory` :

```java
    @Entity
    public class Transaction implements Serializable{

    @Id
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    private BusinessCategory businessCategory;
    ...
    }
```

Within a `@Service`, I retrieve a List that in turn goes through processing of which one of the step involves:

```java
BusinessCategory category = transaction.getBusinessCategory();
if(transaction.getBusinessCategory().getParentCategory()!=null){
   ...
   /** do stuff **/
}
```

What's really odd is that even though my test transaction has a BusinessCategory with a parent, `transaction.getBusinessCategory().getParentCategory()` just returns `null` (seen as the `handler` object in the Debugger).  Even odder is the fact that I am able to access the property of the `parentCategory` directly.  Watch window screenshot:

[image]

I have also confirmed that when one of the properties of parentCategory is accessed, a MySQL query is immediately fired (which is good). I verified by turning on MySQL's general_log & tailing it.

```java
1933 Query  select businessca0_.id as id1_3_0_, businessca0_.dateCreated as dateCrea2_3_0_, businessca0_.dateUpdated as dateUpda3_3_0_, businessca0_.categoryType as category4_3_0_, businessca0_.depth as depth5_3_0_, businessca0_.mappedIds as mappedId6_3_0_, businessca0_.name as name7_3_0_, businessca0_.parentCategory_id as parentCa8_3_0_ from BusinessCategory businessca0_ where businessca0_.id=10013
```

This appears to be a Spring framework bug at play?

Comment: Looks more to me that your debugger is triggering the calls. Using a debugger can have unwanted side effects. If you put a watch on something like `category.getParentCategory().getName()`, it will result in the debugger loading the relationship. _I have also confirmed that when one of the properties of parentCategory is accessed, a MySQL query is immediately fired_ That's actually the point of LazyLoading. If you need to access a property of the relationship, JPA has no other choice than fetching the relationship.

Comment: I am pretty sure I have ruled out the debugger as the culprit.  The fact that the `parentCategory` isn't actually refreshed is the problem.  Also, I turned on the watch window only after noticing the very same symptoms in my logs.  Agreed that the MySQL query being fired is by design (the concept of lazy-loading isn't lost on me). I'm just pointing out that lazy-load appears to be triggered (half working, because the actual object isn't refreshed)

Comment: I am not sure I get what your problem is. In case of lazy-loading, most of the job is done using javaassist and most of the calls are actually delegated to the `handler`. So you cannot rely on what the debugger shows you. You can only rely on what the methods return to you. So far, I cannot understand what is the wrong behaviour in your question.

Comment: `category.getParentCategory()` returns null even though the DB retrieved the parentCategory.  does that make clarify things?

Comment: From what your debugger displays, it seems that it does not return null but actually returns something (`category.getParentCategory()` does not show null in your debugger window).